# .class:hover not working in firefox?

Tags: html, css

So i have some html:

```
<a class='clicktext'>...read more!</a>
```

and i want to give it a :hover animation, as so:

```
.clicktext{
}
.clicktext:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.clicktext:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Suffice to say, it does not work in Mozilla Firefox 5, even though it works perfectly well in Chrome and Safari. However, if i change it to

```
a{
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It works perfectly fine in Mozilla Firefox 5! I have not managed to find anything regarding this online.

I could, of course, just change my styles to apply to the a rather than the .clicktext. The problem with that is that it would screw up my conventions, which is (as far as possible) apply all the styles to classes rather than to the tag names. After all, I have many other  tags for which i do not want this underline-on-hover thing to appear.

Has anyone bumped into this, and perhaps found a nice solution?

edit: these also do not work

```
.clicktext a:hover{...}
a .clicktext:hover{...}
```

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/CQr5r Your edit doesn't work because `a` **is** `.clicktext`, one isn't a child of the other.

Comment: The JSFiddle you gave worked! The exact same code i have on my site doesn't! RARRRGH!!!!

Comment: It's hard to determine anything without seeing more code. Inspect your page in Firebug and see if there's anything overriding the styles.

Comment: do not use <a> tag if you are not linking the text to a link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had these kind of problems with Firefox and solved it by adding the tag name to class name:

for example I had this which worked in Chrome but not in Firefox:

```
.content .sidebar:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

and fixed it by making it more specific like this:

```
div.content div.sidebar:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: why this works, I have no idea, but this quick fix saved the day for me.

Comment: a.class:hover{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);} doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @Fuseteam If you're working on the html snippet in the question, `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);` shouldn't have any effect, as the alpha is set to 0. What do you expect to happen for this?

Comment: @KamyarInfinity .class has the alpha set to 0.56 so i was expecting it to remove it? but for some reason i can't seem to find it in firefox devtools

Comment: @Fuseteam Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/c7z6q8u2/ This is essentially doing as you said, and it's working in firefox for me.

Comment: @KamyarInfinity confirmed, i suppose i have another error on my hands that i misidentified

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rE8xU/
I do not see the issue, when moused over it does include an underline.
A possible cause of this issue is the level of importance that the class has.
Such as styles that are set by their identification tag will take over any class styles and so forth.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html
check out cascading order

Lastly, make sure that the css file is properly linked and or embedded 
you can use firefox to check as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add href="#" to your . the :hover meta tag needs the link to have the href property set.

Comment: No, that only applies to `:link` and `:visited`.

Comment: It breaks for non "a" tags as well. My :hover divs (buttons) work fine in chrome and safari but also break in FF5 =(

Answer (score 0):

use `<p></p>` tag if you are not hyperlinking the text.

```
<p class='clicktext'>...read more!</p>
```

then for styling the text.

```
p.clicktext {
color: #ccc;
}

p.clicktext:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Hope i Helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a big chance that you have a conflict somewhere in your CSS, because the jsfiddle with this exact code works fine in Firefox 5. You might want to check for ID-selectors with the hover-pseudoclass that could possibly overrule this line of styling. Inspect it with [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) to see what css is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this problem for 
1: not specifying the `class` which is `clicktext` in your case, or.

2: object `a` is associated with some other class not compatible with `clicktext` class! 
I am saying this because my website 
is running perfectly without any problem, in both Chrome and Firefox!
I am using `hover` to produce an `overlay` effect! This is what I am doing:

```
.container{
//your specifications
}
.image{
//your specifications
}
.text{
//your specifications
}
.container:hover .text{
//your specifications
}
```

I also think that the answer marked as "correct answer" is not correct.