# Sibling Selector Hover only works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I have a button list. When a button in that list is hovered over, I want a list of states for that region to appear over the button. Everything works in chrome, but in firefox and safari the list of states doesn't appear when the button is hovered over. The background changes color, the pointer changes, but for whatever reason the info div wont appear.

I used this post as a reference and made my selectors more specific but it didnt fix the issue: [.class:hover not working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971350/classhover-not-working-in-firefox)

Here is my button html and the selector css:

```css
.d-region{
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #000000;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .d-region--width{width: 285px; margin: 0 auto;}

        .d-region__head{
            font-size: 24px;
            background-color: #000000;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            text-shadow: 0.4px 0.4px #000000;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 15px;
        }

        .d-region__contain{height: 75px;position: relative;}

        .d-region__btn{
            font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border: 0px;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 300;
            width: 285px;
            height: inherit;
            color: rgb(25, 155, 220);
            z-index: 98;
        }

        .d-region__note{
            font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: rgb(46, 113, 158);
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(237, 248, 234);
            padding: 25px 10px;

        }

        .d-region--border-bottom{border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 235, 205);}

        .d-region__info{display: none;position: absolute;}

        input.d-region__btn:hover + div.d-region__info{
            color: rgb(46, 113, 158);
            font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 2px solid rgb(225, 229, 320);
            width: 275px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: 3px;
            display: inline;
            z-index: 99;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 15px 0px;
            top: -50px;

        }



        input.d-region__btn:hover{background-color: rgb(212, 235, 246);cursor: pointer;}

        div.d-region__contain < div.d-region__info:hover{background-color: rgb(212, 235, 246);}
```

```html
  <div class="d-region d-region--width">
    <div class="d-region__head">Pre-Formatted Regions</div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="West" ID="West" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">AK, AZ, CA, CO, HI, ID, MT, NV, NM, OR, UT, WA, WY</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="NorthEast" ID="NorthEast" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">CT, ME, MA, NH, NJ, NY, PA, RI, VT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="Mid Atlantic" ID="Mid Atlantic" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">DE, DC, MD, NJ, NY, PA, VA, WV</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="MidWest" ID="MidWest" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">IL, IN, IA, KS, MI, MN, MO, NE, ND, OH, SD, WI</div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="South" ID="South" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">AL, AK, FL, GA, KY, LA, MS, NC, SC, TN, TX</div>
      </div>
        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `left:0;` to `input.d-region__btn:hover + div.d-region__info`

```css
.d-region{
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.d-region--width{width: 285px; margin: 0 auto;}

.d-region__head{
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-shadow: 0.4px 0.4px #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.d-region__contain{height: 75px;position: relative;}

.d-region__btn{
  font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 285px;
  height: inherit;
  color: rgb(25, 155, 220);
  z-index: 98;
}

.d-region__note{
  font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(46, 113, 158);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(237, 248, 234);
  padding: 25px 10px;

}

.d-region--border-bottom{border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 235, 205);}

.d-region__info{display: none;position: absolute;}

input.d-region__btn:hover + div.d-region__info{
  color: rgb(46, 113, 158);
  font-family: Veranda, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgb(225, 229, 320);
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  top: -50px;
  left:0;

}



input.d-region__btn:hover{background-color: rgb(212, 235, 246);cursor: pointer;}

div.d-region__contain < div.d-region__info:hover{background-color: rgb(212, 235, 246);}
```

```html
<div class="d-region d-region--width">
    <div class="d-region__head">Pre-Formatted Regions</div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="West" ID="West" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">AK, AZ, CA, CO, HI, ID, MT, NV, NM, OR, UT, WA, WY</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="NorthEast" ID="NorthEast" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">CT, ME, MA, NH, NJ, NY, PA, RI, VT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="Mid Atlantic" ID="Mid Atlantic" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">DE, DC, MD, NJ, NY, PA, VA, WV</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="MidWest" ID="MidWest" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">IL, IN, IA, KS, MI, MN, MO, NE, ND, OH, SD, WI</div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <input type="button" value="South" ID="South" class="d-region__btn"/>
        <div class="d-region__info">AL, AK, FL, GA, KY, LA, MS, NC, SC, TN, TX</div>
      </div>
        
  </div>
```

Comment: This method fixes the issue in both firefox and safari. Chrome must be more lenient than the other browsers when only setting one position (top) rather than both (top and left)?

Comment: Yes, chrome can handle this issue without giving it the both ( top and left) , but you should use the both because of the other browsers. you also have another solution but I forget to mention it in my answer -- you can fix this problem by giving your input.region__btn display:block;

Answer (score 1):

Use a div instead of a input and it works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/mept66L5/

```
 <div class="d-region__contain d-region--border-bottom">
        <div ID="NorthEast" class="d-region__btn">NorthEast</div>
        <div class="d-region__info">CT, ME, MA, NH, NJ, NY, PA, RI, VT</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer does create the desired effect, but in my case I need them to be asp input buttons that submit to a code behind. Changed them to standard html for this question. Wasn't expecting a div change to make a difference :)